# Eventually , is enum a class?

Tags: java

If I write an enum like below ,

```
public enum States{
}
```

IDE is generating `.class` file `States.class` in target, same as if I would have written a class named - `States`

So here , does `.class` file simply tells me existence of Java byte code for `enum` type or does it mean that enum is eventually a type of Java `Class` type?

Comment: @Tunaki - the question linked by you doesn't answer my question directly.There is this [blog post](http://boyns.blogspot.nl/2008/03/java-15-explained-enum.html) in one of answers which answers my question -  **The Direction enum is really a Java class (in this case an inner class within this Enum class example) and it has a static field named EAST. Looking a little closer you can see that the field EAST is also Direction object** . My question is more specific and answers posted here answer it too.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes enum are type of Java Class.** 

The **values** of an `enum` are the only possible **instances** of this class.

Answer (score -1):

Sure it is. Check it's [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
extends Object
implements Comparable<E>, Serializable
```

> This is the common base class of all Java language enumeration types.